# Google NDB update only specific property?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a way to update only specific property on NDB entity?

Consider this example.

Entity A has following property:
property B
property C

Let's assume both of these properties have values of 1 at the moment.

Two different request are trying to update same entity and they are happening at the same time.
So when Request#1 and #2 are retrieving this entity, value of B and C were 1.

Now Request #1 tries to update property B so it sets the value B to 2 and put into Datastore. Now B = 2 and C = 1 in the datastore.
But, Request #2 has B=1 and C=1 in the memory and when it change C to 2 and put into DB, it put's B=1 and C=2 which overwrites B value written by Request #1.

How do you get around this? Is there way to only write specific property into datastore?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may want to look into transactions.

As per the documentation:

> If the transaction "collides" with another, it fails; NDB automatically retries such failed transactions a few times. Thus, the function may be called multiple times if the transaction is retried.

Link: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/transactions

Comment: It might work, but there is no guarantee due to ndb's eventual consistency mechanism. Eg. if the 2nd transaction is happening right after the first, it could still grab the old data and overwrite it. I guess there is no way to update only selective properties?

Comment: Eventual consistencies are only for query from multiple entity group. Means if you can already access your data you get the updated one. Also key based get isn't affected by it. Then under the hood I believe that changed property is the only one really updated. You can verify this by looking at appstats where the only computed index write costs are reflected on changed property (not 100% sure).